# Select the newest folder and copy this folders contain to another place batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need some help regarding this issue:

I have a folder which is `C:\Folder1` and this folder contains several sub-folders and the subfolders contain some files. My question is how can I select the newest folder and how to copy the files in this new folder to another location on Windows?

I plan to do this by using a batch file or whatever:)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad /o-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO ECHO(XCOPY /s "%sourcedir%\%%a" "destination\"&GOTO done
)
:done

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required XCOPY commands is merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the command is correct**, change `ECHO(XCOPY` to `XCOPY` to actually copy the files. The terminating `\` on the destination string ensures that the destination directory is created if it doesn't already exist